# Discord-component button help interaction failed

Tags: python, discord.py

So im using this code and i have from discord_components import * and DiscordComponents(bot) in on_ready. I did pip install --update discord-components. This is the code im using.

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(
        "This is a button test :smile:",
        components =[
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label ="Button 1"),
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label ="Button 2"),
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label ="this is a picture", url="https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2020/02/france-in-pictures-beautiful-places-to-photograph-eiffel-tower.jpg" ),
        ],
    )
    component = discord.Component
    interaction1 = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Button 1"))
    await interaction1.respond(content = "Button 1 Seems like it working")
    

    interaction2 = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Button 2"))
    await interaction2.respond(content = "Button 2 Seems like it working")
```

There is no error message and when I do $button it prints but if I click on a button it says interaction failed(still no error message) I'm new to button so if you could help me that would be great